# Order grouped entries

Tags: templating, entries, group, order

I need to group and order member profiles alphabetically but I can't get it to work. Have a look here: http://ffsd.de.w0129b45.kasserver.com/mitglieder
(It's german but you should get the idea :))

In everything I tried either the groups are ordered correctly or the contents (profiles) of the group are… but never both. Here's the relevant code:

```
{% set allProfiles = craft.entries.section('members').order('profileLastname').limit(null) %}
{% for letter, profiles in allProfiles|group("profileAlphabet") %}
    <ul class="member__index">
        <li class="item letter">
            <span id="{{ letter }}">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <span class="initials letter">{{ letter }}</span>
                </div>
            </span>
        </li>

        {% for profile in profiles %}
            <li class="item">
                <a href="{{ profile.url }}"><h3>{{ profile.title }}</h3></a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, I'd like to order the profiles by the custom field "profileLastname" and the groups by "profileAlphabet".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probably most easy way to do this is to sort the grouped array by key, which unfortunatelly is only possible with
a plugin, as Twig's [`sort`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/sort.html) filter only allows to sort by value.

Here I'm using Michael Rog's [Supersort](https://topshelfcraft.com/lagniappe/supersort), but there are also other plugins that do this.

```
{% set allProfiles = craft.entries.section('members').order('profileLastname').limit(null) %}
{% set allProfilesGrouped = allProfiles|group("profileAlphabet")|supersort('ksort') %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this looking to answer similar problem. You should be able to do this now without a plugin, using the [multisort filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#multisort) where you iterate through your profiles, e.g.:

```
{% for profile in profiles|multisort(['profileLastname'],[SORT_ASC],[SORT_REGULAR]) %}
```